# When I'm using redux, should I always keep the response in the global state even the result will be used only once?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Currently, I have a form where my users fill fields like name, email, address, university, etc. However, we have a list of universities that comes from our API. This request is made via redux-saga and the response fill a select in the view.

I understand that redux-saga helps me to manage async operations but keep this response on my global state where I will use only once looks weird.

Is there any answer or patterns where I can see or understand clearly?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, the short answer is no, you shouldn't keep data in your Redux store unless it will continue to be relevant to the rest of your app.

If you're using Redux-Saga to handle async data fetching actions, what you could do is pass `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks in your action for the saga to call after the async call is done. For example, using react hooks you could do something like:

```
const SelectUniversity = ({getUniversities}) => {
  let [universities, setUniversities] = useState({
      fetched: false
  });

  const handleSuccess = (items) => {
      setUniversities({
          fetched: true,
          items: items
      });
  }

  const handleFailure = (error) => {
      setUniversities({
          fetched: true,
          error
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      if(!universities.fetched){
          getUniversities(
              {foo: bar}, // async call params if any needed
              handleSuccess,
              handleFailure
          )
      }
  }, [universities])

  return !universities.fetched
    ? <Spinner />          // if universities not fetched yet, show loading spinner
    : !universities.error  // if fetched and no error, display results
        ? <Select items={universities.items} />
        : /* if fetched and error, handle error case here */;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getUniversities: (params, onSuccess, OnFailure) => dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_UNIVERSITIES',
      payload: { params, onSuccess, OnFailure }
  }),
})

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SelectUniversity)
```

And then in your sagas file you'd do something like:

```
function* fetchUniversities({type, payload}){
  const { params, onSuccess, OnFailure } = payload;
  try{
    const universities = yield call(fetchUniversities, params); // your actual async fetch call
    yield call(onSuccess, universities);
  }catch(err){
    yield call(OnFailure, err);
  }
}

export function* watchFetchUniversities() {
  yield takeLeading('FETCH_UNIVERSITIES', fetchUniversities)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, now is more than clear!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely no. `Redux`'s state is for [`non-ephemeral`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1287) data:

> Use React for ephemeral state that doesn't matter to the app globally and doesn't mutate in complex ways. For example, a toggle in some UI element, a form input state. Use Redux for state that matters globally or is mutated in complex ways. For example, cached users, or a post draft.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.